# Convert a OneNote file (without using OneNote) so that it can be read by onother program

Tags: microsoft-onenote

My Microsoft OneNote 2010 has stopped working. Is there any way to bypass OneNote and convert a OneNote file to a format that can be read by another program?

Comment: Alternatively, have you tried doing a repair install on OneNote? Or backup your files and reinstall?

Answer (score 3):

If you have [Evernote](https://evernote.com/) then you can import your onenote notes. See [How to Import Notes from OneNote into Evernote](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/11172/how-to-import-notes-from-onenote-into-evernote/) for more information.

**Summary**:

1. Launch Evernote and log in to your account.
2. Go to File->Import->Microsoft OneNote.
3. In the pop up window, select the notebook and sections you want to import, hit OK to process.
4. By default, all your notes will be placed in a notebook called “Personal“. If you want to put them in a synchronized notebook, click Yes. If you only want to store them in a local notebook, just hit No.

Answer (score -1):

If your note is a simple text file, you might want to save the file into text then change the extension into .File.

You should send an email to inform the recipient that he can open those files with *OPEN WITH*.

Notepad doesn't have any Formatting Option, it's just plain ASCII. It should allow you to make the file readable to anyone.

If you have stickers on your desktop and you want to import them, you can follow the tip above. I have no solution to convert your stickers in an universal format.

--

I have searched what OneNote is. There's multiple formats that can be found in the file in those kinds of file. There is a Web Based OneNote that you could use to open and edit OneNotes online. It would allow you to convert your OneNote into raw form files if you don't want to install any program but make it simply readable.